# Trouble with parsing response from GET request in Android

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-volley

I have trouble when parsing the following response in Android:

```
{"success":true,"msg":"Okay","result":{"content_type_id":"2","Content_Type_Name":"Media"}}
```

I need to have the *content_type_id* retrieved, so I can use it in a set method.

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                // This is where I'm stuck.
            }
```

Some of the errors I got `are not able to convert to JSONArray` and `no value for`.

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code,
Write this code inside `onResponse` method.

```
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);

        JSONObject resultObject = jsonObject.has("result") ? jsonObject.optJSONObject("result") : new JSONObject();
        String contentId = resultObject.has("content_type_id") ? resultObject.optString("content_type_id") : "";

        Log.d("content_type_id", contentId);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Pleasure is all mine :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no JSONArray in your response. Convert in into JSONObject.

```
JsonObject jsonObject=new JsonObject(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `JsonObjectRequest` replace to `StringRequest`;

```
  JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, url, jsonObj,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    printlog("response", response + "");
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            callback.serviceCallback(callbackId, null);

            String message = null;
            if (volleyError instanceof NetworkError) {
                message = "Cannot connect to Internet...Please check your connection!";
                Toast.makeText(getInstance(),message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (volleyError instanceof ServerError) {
                message = "The server could not be found. Please try again after some time!!";
                Toast.makeText(getInstance(),message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (volleyError instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                message = "Cannot connect to Internet...Please check your connection!";
                Toast.makeText(getInstance(),message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if (volleyError instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                message = "Cannot connect to Internet...Please check your connection!";
                Toast.makeText(getInstance(),message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (volleyError instanceof TimeoutError) {
                message = "Connection TimeOut! Please check your internet connection.";
                Toast.makeText(getInstance(),message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });


    jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(5000 * 60, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    // Adding request to request queue
    try {
        getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, url);

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The others are on track, but you need to go a bit further. Vishal Chhodwani has a good answer too, and it includes a bit of validation.

First, convert the response into a JSONObject as they suggest. Then retrieve the result from response as a JSONObject. And finally, get the content_type_id from the result.

```
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
JSONObject jsonResult = jsonResponse.getJSONObject("result");
String contentTypeID = jsonResult.getString("content_type_id");
```

Additionally, if you are expecting **content_type_id** to be an `int` for your set method, you can try this instead:

```
int contentTypeID = jsonResult.getInt("content_type_id");
```

For more detailed information, here is a link to the Android Documentation for JSONObject: https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html